# Creating a SQL friends table to store

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have taken it on myself to create a site that allows users to add each other as friends and comment on each others posts. After looking into this I'm not sure exactly how to start. I have a posts and a users table.

My question is how would I relate the databases to
1.Check if user A has sent a friend request to user B?
2.Store a value to indicate that they are friends?

I've browsed around this site before posting but can't seem to understand how to carry this out. Pretty sure I'm just over complicating it. Could anyone explain the concept or how this works?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This could be done with a relational database, and it would be worth reading up on how relational databases work e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvrpuBAMddw

But - to give some pointers, it looks like yor want your relational database to allow for the following functions:

- a number of users
- a series of posts, by certain users
- a number of relationships between users
- an ability to verify a relationship before it is confirmed
- a series of posts, by certain users
- a number of 'sub-post' comments on posts

1) Let's start with the 'friend request' section.

This would need you to have a) a whole load of different users, and b) a load of relationships between those users.

You'd need to represent that in 2 different tables - so create a `users` table with the following fields:

```
UserID, name, age, [details, password, address etc etc]
```

and then a `friends` table which has these fields:

```
friendID, userID1, userID2, [date, confirmed]
```

Your user table might look like this:

```
 UserID,  name,     age,
   1      Fred      18
   2     George     24
   3     Michael    20
   4     Alice      24
   5     Sophie     20
   6     George     19
```

Let's say that Michael wants to become friends with Alice and Fred, and Alice wants to befriend Sophie - you'd want to create records in your friends table that looked like this:

```
 FriendID, userID1,                            userID2,
   1         3  (this refers to Michael)         4 (this refers to Alice)
   2         3  (this refers to Michael)         1 (this refers to Fred)
   3         4  (this refers to Alice)           5 (this refers to Sophie)
```

So if you then looked for Michael's friends - you'd do a query which looked for:

```
 every record from the friend table where userID1 = Michael's userID. 

 From the userID2 field, you'd get userID 4 and userID 1 

 By looking up those userids in the user table, you'd find more details for Alice and Fred.
```

You should make this query check whether userID1 **OR** userid2 = the userID you need, so that you get the same results if e.g. the table looked slightly differently:

```
 FriendID, userID1,                            userID2,
   1         3  (this refers to Michael)         4 (this refers to Alice)
   2         1  (this refers to Fred)            3 (this refers to Michael)
   3         4  (this refers to Alice)           5 (this refers to Sophie)

Otherwise you'd only know about Alice.. but you want to know about Fred too.
```

2) If you want to confirm a relationship, you could add a 'confirmed' field to the friends table - set it to binary 0 = not confirmed / 1 = confirmed.

When the friendship is requested, you add the record to the table, but when it is confirmed, you would update the 'confirmed' field for that record to 1.

Let's update our friends table accordingly:

```
 FriendID, userID1,               userID2,     confirmed
   1         3  (Michael)         4 (Alice)      0
   2         3  (Michael)         1 (Fred)       1
   3         4  (Alice)           5 (Sophie)     1
```

If you want to see all friends that are pending Michael's acceptance, you'd search for:

```
  any records from the friends table where userid1 = 3
  AND confirmed = 0 ... which means it hasn't been accepted yet.
```

This would show that alice hasn't yet been accepted as a friend by Michael.

If you want to see all friends a user had requested but which haven't been accepted you'd look for:

```
  any records from the friends table where userid2 = the user you're looking for
  AND confirmed = 0 ... which means it hasn't been accepted yet.
```

If you want to see all accepted friends, switch 'confirmed' to 1.

3) You also wanted to have posts for each user... so you'll need a `posts` table with fields for:

```
postid, userid, date, content
```

We've already got your user table, so let's say that Michael wanted to post some stuff. The posts table might look like this:

```
postid, userid,          date               content
  1       3 (Michael)    [auto datetime]     Hi everyone   
  2       3 (Michael)    [auto datetime]     This is my second post
```

You've now got a relationship between Michael and the posts table. If another user posted something, they'd add another line with a different userid. You can then retrieve all the posts from the posts table where the userid = 3, which is Michael's userid.

4) To add comments on posts you would need a comments table that might look like this:

```
commentid, postid,          userid               content
  1           1               3 (Michael)         Michael is commenting on his own first post...
  2           2               4 (Alice)           Alice is saying something on Michael's second post
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth reply. This reply was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry if the question was too broad. I have a hard time explaining sometimes.

Comment: What if you wanted to lookup Sophie's friends? Your sql would not return anything when it should return 4

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the answer.